# How can I add "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" on a column at table creation or by alter table withoud defining its default value

Tags: mysql

I am using following query to alter a table and add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on a column.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE column_name column_name TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP // can I remove this line
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

From the above query, Can I put `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on a column **without defining its default value**?

When I try to remove that part, the query will be like:

```
alter table new_table CHANGE updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and it is showing error: **alter table new_table CHANGE updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'updated_at'**

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: you can't have `not null` and then not set a default in this instance.

Comment: What is the *current* definition of the table?

Comment: new_table, CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE t1
  MODIFY COLUMN c1
  TIMESTAMP
  NULL -- the opposite is NOT NULL, which is implicitly set on timestamp columns
  DEFAULT NULL -- no default value for newly-inserted rows
  ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

> ALTER TABLE table_name
> CHANGE COLUMN updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;